# Pasting from several rows into a single row every 6th cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I need to copy every 6 cells down horizontal to a new column

So that `D3/E3/F3/G3/H3/I3` goes to `J2/K2/L2/M2/N2/O2`
And that `D4/E4/F4/G4/H4/I4` goes to `P2/Q2/R2/S2/T2/U2`

And so on for sets of 20 rows

I swear I did it before, do not know VBA but am stumped other than manual paste

Comment: ...every 6 cells not 7 sorry

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have output from one program that has my data in sets of 6 columns and 20 rows per datapoint (person)  I need the 20 rows (in 6 cell sets) to fit into one long row.

Comment: Only way I know is to split the screen 4 ways and copy paste blocks

Comment: Why don't you skip putting a newline in your "program" instead?

Answer (score 2):

> I have output from one program that has my data in sets of 6 columns and 20 rows per datapoint (person) I need the 20 rows (in 6 cell sets) to fit into one long row.

Use Notepad++ and its RegEx feature to remove line breaks to get a single date row.

[image]

1. Save the Excel file as .CSV and open it with [Notepad++](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable)
2. Replace the *newline* character `\r\n` with your corresponding delimiter `;` or `,`

   [[image]

   <sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IywRd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the following formula into J2 and copy across to the right:

`=OFFSET(J2,ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN()-4)/6,0),-6*ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN()-4)/6,0))`